# have to restart phone again to get camera working

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

Hey guys
I am accessing camera through my application.
It is all well and i can even save a photo to my sd card but

when i capture the image the application seems to get stucked plus if i go to home and den return to the application again i have a force close error. The following is the error i get in logcat

```
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:118)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:91)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at org.mycamera.mycamera.surfaceCreated(mycamera.java:70)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:540)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:339)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6742)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1648)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6742)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1872)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1422)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1167)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1744)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-13 17:20:40.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Following is the code :-

```
SurfaceHolder holder;
SurfaceView  surface;
Camera camera;
Boolean isPreviewRunning;
//Preview mpreview;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    isPreviewRunning = false;
    surface = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surface);
    holder = surface.getHolder();
  holder.addCallback(this);
  holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

  Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.click);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            camera.takePicture(mShutterCallback, mPictureCallbackRaw, mPictureCallbackJpeg);
            //onCreate(null);
        }

    });

}


@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
/*  if (isPreviewRunning) {  
          camera.stopPreview();  
         }  */

    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

    List<Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    Size size = sizes.get(0);
    parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);

    camera.setParameters(parameters);
     camera.startPreview();  
     isPreviewRunning=true;
}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     camera = Camera.open();
     try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    camera=null;
}

 protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {

 super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
 }

 Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallbackRaw = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
 public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera c) {
  Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "PICTURE CALLBACK RAW: " + data);
  camera.startPreview();
 }
 };

 Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallbackJpeg= new Camera.PictureCallback() {
 public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera c) {
  Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "PICTURE CALLBACK JPEG: data.length = " + data);
 }
 };

 Camera.ShutterCallback mShutterCallback = new Camera.ShutterCallback() {
 public void onShutter() {
 Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "SHUTTER CALLBACK");
 }
 };

 protected void onResume()
 {

 Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onResume");
 super.onResume();
 }

 protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
 {
 super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
 }

 protected void onStop()
 {
 Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onStop");
 super.onStop();
 }
```

Comment: See if you can get any inputs from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001179/cannot-run-android-camera-preview-sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, it's because your calling `startPreview()` again too early.  From the SDK documentation on `Camera.takePicture()`:

> After calling this method, you must not call startPreview() or take another picture until the JPEG callback has returned.

You are calling `startPreview()` to restart the preview frames in your `mPictureCallbackRaw`, when you should wait until the `mPictureCallbackJpeg`.  This is probably messing with the Camera service and putting it into a weird state.

Hope that Helps!